# Imagemagick removing watermark

Tags: imagemagick

Is it possible to remove watermark placed with imagemagick library in past?

Thanks ;)

**Update**

I mean, I need to remove my logo from images. Can't find in official documentation, how to remove watermark from image.

Comment: Unless you place something on top of your logo, it is impossible.

Comment: If the watermark is relatively small on a single image (not video), you can make the watermark region transparent or some color and use pinpointing techniques to try to restore the image in that region. It is not perfect. With multiple frames of a video, you can do a pretty good job using imagemagick and -evaluate-sequent median using 3 successive frames. With one image, once the image data is covered, there is no good way to reliably remove the watermark. Using the watermark image, you can remove it from the background image

Comment: CONTINUED: For video, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178490/performing-multiple-image-averaging-in-c-sharp/24179962?r=SearchResults#24179962. For single images, see https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29345&p=131345&hilit=inpaint#p131345. Also https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you restore the original file directory from a backup. I'm presuming that you've rendered a single-layered file, where IM composited/overlayed the watermark on the image. There is no reliable and practical way to remove such a mark generally manually, let alone via batch process. Exceptions might include if the watermark always rendered over a flat color, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The logo can be removed easily using ffmpeg, by using its delogo filter. All you need to supply is the co-ordinates and dimensions of the logo present on the video.

This works on videos very swiftly, you can convert your image to a video and apply this filter, or even compile group of images to a video and later break it into frames to obtain clean images. All of this can be easily done using ffmpeg only.
eg for the filter syntax: ffmpeg -i (your video url) -f "delogo=x=0:y=0:w=100:h=77:band=10" -r (output file url)

Find the complete documentation [here](https://libav.org/documentation/libavfilter.html#delogo).