# Performing multiple image averaging in c#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, aforge

I wish to calculate an average image from 3 different images of the same size that I have. I know this can be done with ease in matlab..but how do I go about this in c#? Also is there an Aforge.net  tool I can use directly for this purpose?

Comment: Could you please explain what does image average mean? Is it pixel RGB average of the three images?

Comment: Yeah @RobertJ. RGB averaging is what I mean

Comment: Do you want the process to be fast or easy?

Comment: Fast!..I've tried locking the bitmaps and taking the average of the RGB values and assigning it to the result image but I'm getting absurd results...

Comment: Well, LockBits would be the way to go imho. Maybe the problem was in your calculations? How did you get the average of RGB values? did you try to average values of each R | G | B for three images or you simply multiplied value of R*G*B for each image and average the values?

Comment: Please post your code that gives absurd results, you may only have a single character/digit wrong in there that someone can spot easily rather than rewriting everything.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an article on SO which might point you in the right direction. Here is the code (unsafe)

```
BitmapData srcData = bm.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), 
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

int stride = srcData.Stride;

IntPtr Scan0 = srcData.Scan0;

long[] totals = new long[] {0,0,0};

int width = bm.Width;
int height = bm.Height;

unsafe
{
  byte* p = (byte*) (void*) Scan0;

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
      for (int color = 0; color < 3; color++)
      {
        int idx = (y*stride) + x*4 + color;

        totals[color] += p[idx];
      }
    }
  }
}

int avgB = totals[0] / (width*height);
int avgG = totals[1] / (width*height);
int avgR = totals[2] / (width*height);
```

Here is the link to the article:
[How to calculate the average rgb color values of a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068373/how-to-calculate-the-average-rgb-color-values-of-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can do this for you very simply - at the command-line you could type this:

```
convert *.bmp -evaluate-sequence mean output.jpg
```

You could equally calculate the median (instead of the mean) of a bunch of TIFF files and save in a PNG output file like this:

```
convert *.tif -evaluate-sequence median output.png
```

Easy, eh?

There are bindings for C/C++, Perl, PHP and all sorts of other janguage interfaces, including (as kindly pointed out by @dlemstra) the Magick.Net binding available [here](http://imagemagick.org/script/api.php#dot-net).

ImageMagick is powerful, free and available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Comment: There is a binding for C# called Magick.NET (http://imagemagick.org/script/api.php#dot-net)

Comment: @dlemstra +1 Thank you for that insight - it's good to learn new stuff :-)

Comment: Can you modify your answer?